# Change bounding box in Figma

Tags: bounding-box, figma

[image: Figma]

I want to export icons in the same width and height, for example, say I want all of them to be exported as 30x30. So, in short I'd like to change bounding box of the icons in Figma without scaling them.

is that possible?
or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the bounding box is set to Frame (not group). You can scale just the frame bounding by pressing and holding Command / Control while you resize.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with just a transparent rectangles(30x30) behind them and grouped each of them, and when exported those icons become 30x30 ^